# Get textarea data. [Froala Editor] [Codeigniter]

Tags: php, codeigniter, textarea, codeigniter-3, froala

I try to get data from text area,When submit form.

```
<?php
        echo form_open_multipart('start/create','class="build_form"');
            ...
            echo form_textarea('proDetail','','id="proDetail"');
            ...
            echo form_submit('submit','Save','class="btn btn-primary"');
        echo form_close();
?>
```

Try to show data in this function.

```
public function create()
{       
    echo print_r($this->input->post('proDetail'));
}
```

It give me a data from textarea, But it's not same when look in textarea.

How it look in textarea.
[image]
This is code in textarea.

```
<p><img class="fr-draggable fr-fir fr-dii" style="width: 300px;" src="http://localhost/siamfunding/img/users/upload/3a5e29ad7b5c64b16a97c56ce2a006cb7f66c7e3.jpg"></p>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">
<strong>asdasddadasdddd</strong>
</h1>
<p style="margin-left: 20px;">qwdqwdasdasasdwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww</p>
<p style="">daaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaas</p>
<p style="">dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
<p style="">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaad</p>
```

And, This is how it look when i try to show data.
[image]
This is code.

```
<p>
   <img class="fr-draggable fr-fir fr-dii" xss="removed" src="http://localhost/siamfunding/img/users/upload/3a5e29ad7b5c64b16a97c56ce2a006cb7f66c7e3.jpg">
</p>
<h1 xss="removed">
<strong>asdasddadasdddd</strong>
</h1>
<p xss="removed">qwdqwdasdasasdwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww</p>
<p xss="removed">daaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaas</p>
<p xss="removed">dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
<p xss="removed">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaad</p>
<p xss="removed">
   <br>
</p>
```

What happen, How can i make it look like in text area.

Ps.I try to import css and Jquery in page. It's not work.

Comment: Is `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;` in `config.php`? If so, set it to FALSE.